# Print 2 pages PDF on one sheet with 1.5x enlargement

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe, adobe-reader

I need to print 2 pages on a single sheet (like in a book), but at the same time enlarge each page 1.5 times. Is there a way to do it in Adobe Reader or any other software?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While Printing option you can just try "Multiple" in "**Page Sizing and Handling"** option.

there you can get what exactly you need.

Comment: well, I didn't see where I could enlarge each page before fitting 2 of them on sheet.